# Max IF While Filtering dates?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, max

How can I find the max date that is less than today in a range that is mixed with both ACTUAL and PROJECTED Dates:
[image]

as you see here I have a row of dates. Some dates are actual, others are projected. I want to open the spreadsheet and say "What is the latest PROJECTED date that is less than today?"

Comment: Projected date is listed in the image - it's rotated 90 deg CCW... I'm wondering - why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in a single formula, you will need to use an Array formula. Array formulas calculate something multiple times, once for each cell in a range, and provide you with an array of responses. To solve part 1 of what you're asking, the array formula would look like this (Assuming your columns end at H, and are on row 2 only):

```
=MAX(if(A1:H1="PROJECTED",A2:H2,""))
```

When this is typed into the formula bar, confirm with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, instead of just ENTER. It will look like this afterwards (do not type the {} yourself):

```
{=MAX(if(A1:H1="PROJECTED",A2:H2,""))}
```

This looks at each cell from A1:H1. Where it says "PROJECTED", it then gives the value in A2:H2 for that column [otherwise it gives ""]. To find which date is the highest, we wrap it in the MAX function.

But we're not done, because you have other criteria. Normally you could use the AND function for this, but AND functions take array results and collapse them into a single value. So we need to use the natural TRUE / FALSE function of the IF statement instead, like so:

```
=MAX(if(A1:H1="PROJECTED",if(A2:H2<today(),A2:H2,""),""))
```

This checks where in row 1 = "PROJECTED", while at the same time that column in row 2 is less than the value of today's date. It then provides you with that date. It takes the highest date shown. Remember to confirm with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, instead of just ENTER.

Comment: That was right, but I still was getting an answer that I didn't expect. I realized in addition to checking for the cell that was less than today, I had to check for the cells that were greater than zero (otherwise all cells met the condition of being less than today). That, then, got me the behavior I was seeking.

Comment: =MAX(IF(J$4:AG$4="Projected",IF(J170:AG170<TODAY(),IF(J170:AG170>0,J$1:AG$1,""),"")))

Comment: @SimaPro Good call; glad I got you on the right track.